# React-Native Windows missing directories

Tags: node.js, windows, react-native

I´m developping a react-native app on windows. I have react-native 2.0.1.

The development runs fine, but often it leads to an inconsistent state, whereas some of the directories of the application are not served, i.e, some javascript files are not bundled leading to some require/import issues.

I found it out by looking at the chrome debugger sources tab where I noticed only a portion of the whole project was served.

I don´t know how to troubleshoot this issue. 
It happens inconsistently. The application "starts fine", however whenever I face this particular scenario I notice the following log message:

```
[1/15/2017, 10:38:42 PM] <START> Symbolicating
[1/15/2017, 10:38:42 PM] <END>   Symbolicating (204ms)
[1/15/2017, 10:38:43 PM] <START> Symbolicating
[1/15/2017, 10:38:43 PM] <END>   Symbolicating (181ms)
```

Is there any hints on how to troubleshoot it?

I´m on windows 10, react-native 2.0.1 and node 7.2.0 using genymotion

I´m running

react-native start
react-native android-run

Thanks

Comment: 2.0.1 is the version of react-native-cli. Can you tell us the version of the react-native npm package itself? I personally haven't run into this issue in Windows 7 or 10 with react-native 0.42.